# Model runs in Jupyter notebook but not in Flask

Tags: python, flask, classification

I trained a basic classification model to classify (skin) images into 3 classes (skin types), in which user would upload a photo and the model would generate a prediction as output. The code runs fine in Jupyter Notebook but an Internal server error pops up once I tried to upload the picture in Flask... Sorry that I don't have a more specific question but it's the first time trying to deploy in Flask and don't really know what is wrong. I appreciate any help or advice!

The html files (and therefore the interface)look fine; this is the only .py file I have in the dir

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import numpy as np
import pickle
import uuid
import base64

fn = 'lr_skin_classification'
model_dir = '../models'
with open('%s/%s.pkl' % (model_dir, fn), 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '../uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'}


def get_as_base64(url):
    return base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)


# @app.route('/')
# def index():
#    return render_template('index.html')

def predict(file):
    image_size = (64, 64)
    image = np.asarray(Image.open(file).resize(image_size))
    image = np.average(image, axis=2)  # average color-pixel: 3 channel --> 1 channel
    image /= 255 # normalize each pixel from range 0-255 to 0-1
    dimension = image_size[0] * image_size[1]    # flatten the images
    image = image.reshape(image.shape[0], dimension)
    array = model.predict(image)
    result = array[0]
    answer = np.argmax(result)
    if answer == 0:
        print("Label: Normal")
    elif answer == 1:
        print("Label: Dry")
    elif answer == 2:
        print("Label: Oily")
    return answer

def my_random_string(string_length=10):
    """Returns a random string of length string_length."""
    random = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Convert UUID format to a Python string.
    random = random.upper()  # Make all characters uppercase.
    random = random.replace("-", "")  # Remove the UUID '-'.
    return random[0:string_length]  # Return the random string.

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    return render_template('template.html', label='',
                           imagesource='../uploads/template.jpg')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import time
        start_time = time.time()
        file = request.files['file']

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            result = model.predict(file_path)
            final = np.argmax(result)
            if final == 0:
                label: 'Normal'
            elif final == 1:
                label: 'Dry'
            elif final == 2:
                label: 'Oily'
            print(result)
            print(file_path)
            filename = my_random_string(6) + filename

            os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time))
            return render_template('template.html', label=label, imagesource='../uploads/' + filename)


from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

Comment: You need to turn debugging on with `app.debug = True`, and FLASK_DEBUG=1.

Comment: Then run it again and report the more specific error.

Comment: Thanks! I did and figured that there was an error in this line-
image = image.reshape(image.shape[0], dimension)   -- image.shape[0] should be 1 because it's supposed to be the no. of image passed in (which is 1 in this case) * dimension

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The source of my problem was that my app.py flask was designed for grayscale images, but my project uses color images. I changed the following parameter in app.py when the image is loaded:

Grayscale:

`IMG = image.load_img (img_path) .convert ('L')`

Color images:

`IMG = image.load_img (img_path) .convert ('RGB')`